# Pandasで文字列に対して関数を適用したい

Tags: python, pandas

Python3.7です。

```
df['cnt'] = df.x1.count('＄')
```

として、x1列（文字列）に出てくる＄の回数を数えた列を作ろうと考えていますが、

```
KeyError: 'Requested level (＄) does not match index name (None)'
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。
どう対処すればよろしいでしょうか。

**追記**
`df.x1.str.count('＄')`で

```
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

が出ましたが、無事出力できました。
http://anton0825.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/02/01/000000
によるとdf['age'][5]のように[]を二段にしてアクセスすると発生するとのことです。
df.x1.str.count('＄')
が原因のような気がしますが、どうなのでしょうか。

Comment: 追記状況の場合、もっと詳細なOS種別/版数、Python/pandas版数の情報と、エラー発生行&エラーメッセージだけでは無く[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)に従って、他者が推測や仮定無しに問題を再現・調査できるような最小限の完結したソースコードおよびテストデータを提示してください。

Comment: ちなみに検索したらこんな記事があるようなので参考に。[pandas の SettingWithCopyWarning で苦労した話](https://qiita.com/HEM_SP/items/56cd62a1c000d342bd70), [pandasのSettingWithCopyWarningを理解する (1/3)](https://linus-mk.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/02/02/200000), [pandasのSettingWithCopyWarningを理解する (2/3)](https://linus-mk.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/14/235402), [pandasのSettingWithCopyWarningを理解する (3/3)](https://linus-mk.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/18/161328)

Comment: `Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` と表示されているので、`df.loc[:, 'cnt'] = df.x1.str.count('＄')` としてみると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手元の環境(Python 3.6.1, pandas 0.24.2)では下記のコードで動作しました。
x1列のデータをstrにしてから[count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html)を呼び出しています。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['＄', '＄＄', '$', '＄ド＄ル＄'], columns=['x1'])
print(df.x1.str.count('＄'))
# print(df.x1.count('＄'))  # KeyError: 'Level ＄ must be same as name (None)'
```

質問文のコードを実行するとエラーが発生しますが、エラー内容が異なっています。
質問文と同様のエラーが出た時の[本家SOの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939030)ではpandas関連モジュールを更新することで解決すると書かれています。

Comment: Python 3.8.5, pandas 1.1.0でも回答の`df`定義で質問の`df['cnt'] = df.x1.count('＄')`を行うと、質問のエラーになるので、回答としては「`str`を加えて`df['cnt'] = df.x1.str.count('＄')`にする」で良いのでは？